# Shorten a RegEx

Tags: java, regex

In Java RegEx I have the following:

```
(1abc\\d{2})|(2abc\\d{3})|(3abc\\d{4})
```

I would like to extract the 'abc\d' out of the RegEx and replace the RegEx with something like:

```
(1|2|3)abc\\d({2]|{3}|{4})
```

The problem is that 1 belongs to {2} and 2 belongs to {3} and 3 belongs to {4}. So a good match is, 1abc12, but a bad match is 1abc123.

I have recently learned RegEx and I feel like i'm missing some knowledge about RegEx to make this possible. Is it even possible?

Comment: As a possible alternative, relax the matching criteria similar to your second expression (but simpler) and use java logic on capturing groups 1 and 2 to filter the results as good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not possible with regular expressions. In general, a later part of the expression cannot depend on the matching result of an earlier part of the expression. For example, you can't write a regex that matches balanced parenthesis or [matching HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Some implementations provide extensions which give exceptions to this (irregular expressions), but I don't think they apply here.

Comment: Dave Webb his answer is also good, but throwing in the term 'irregular expression' pointed me more in the direction of a good explanation of WHY what i'm trying to do isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use back references via `\n` in Regular Expressions to refer to previously matched groups but these only match strings again, they can't change the rules of the pattern.

For example `(1|2|3)abc\1` would match `1abc1` and `2abc2` but not `1abc2`, i.e the `\1` will match what was found the first bracket.

Ideally, we want to do something lie `(1|2|3)abc\d{\1 + 1}` but Java doesn't support code or expressions within its Regular Expressions.

So unfortunately what you want isn't possible, or rather your first expression is probably as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in a pseudo-conditional way, but the *cure* might be worse than the sickness.

The only way I would use something like this (below) is if the 'text' (`abc` in this case) were something very big to where factoring it out in this way would yield time gains over including it in each alternation as it exists now. An example of some text that would be very large might be '`abc[^\d]+432xyz`', or anything that has open-ended quantifiers or that cause huge backtracking.

This works in Java ..

`"^(?:1()|2()|3())abc(?:(?=\\1)\\d{2}|(?=\\2)\\d{3}|(?=\\3)\\d{4})$"`

(expanded)

```
^       # Begin, all capture buffers are undefined and empty
  (?:
      1()     # If '1' found, set capture buffer 1 to defined (but empty)
    | 2()     # If '2' found, set capture buffer 2 to defined (but empty)
    | 3()     # If '3' found, set capture buffer 3 to defined (but empty)
  )
  abc      # The text factored out
  (?:
       # The below could also be  \1\d{2}|\2\d{3}|\3\d{4} as well

      (?=\1)\d{2}    #     Assertion: is capt buffer 1 defined?, get next two digits
    | (?=\2)\d{3}    # or, Assertion: is capt buffer 2 defined?, get next three digits
    | (?=\3)\d{4}    # or, Assertion: is capt buffer 3 defined?, get next four digits
  )
$      # End
```

Also, as someone mentioned, you could do a general capture, then post-process the result to decide if it is valid.

Something like this:   `^(1|2|3)abc(\d{2,4})$`. then do a switch on capture buffer 1, then cases on the length of capture buffer 2.

Comment: You don't actually have to use lookaheads; `\1\d{2}` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers 1,2,3 are somewhat linked to your regex groups {2}, {3} and {4} respectively, I think there is no way to extact the common subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but you could use string functions to extract the first digit (or a regular expression if the format is not guaranteed to be an appropriate pattern). Then with the first digit, add one, and use it in a very simple regex.